# source() does not recognize global variables when running r post-mortem debugging

Tags: r

I have two scripts:

`run_source.R`:

```
my_var <- "test"
source("source.R")
```

and `source.R`:

```
print(my_var)
```

From a unix terminal I run:

```
 Rscript run_source.R
```

and the system prints the expected:

```
'test'
```

If I modify `run_source.R` for debugging:

```
my_var <- "test"
dump.frames(to.file=TRUE, include.GlobalEnv = TRUE)
source("source.R")
```

Run again:
`Rscript run_source.R`

I still get the expected `"test"`, but when I open an interactive R session and hook back into the debugger:

```
load("last.dump.rda"); debugger(last.dump)
```

and select `1: .GlobalEnv`, I can see `my_var` is in the global environment when I use `ls()`, but as soon as I run:
`source('source.R")` in the debugger, I get an error:
`Error in print(my_var) : object 'my_var' not found`

How do I get the `source('source.R")` to recognize the global variable `my_var` inside the debugger? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

OP here, I think I may have figured it out:

running `source('source.R", local=TRUE)` in the debugger seems to work:

from: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/source

> local: TRUE, FALSE or an environment, determining where the parsed
> expressions are evaluated. FALSE (the default) corresponds to the
> user's workspace (the global environment) and TRUE to the environment
> from which source is called.

I do however, wonder if this default setting changed, as I don't remember having to do this previously.

Comment: You may have just been "lucky" in the past.  Specifying the environment search list is a good thing to do, especially when diving into nested new environments via function calls.

Comment: Thanks for your comments